# absolute URL link in php from database

Tags: php

I have a PHP web application where list of URL of another sites fetch from database and when user click the link they open the external web link in new tab. but whenever I tried to implement this i got relative URL connected to my web app. I want to add an absolute external link.

in my case in **bookmark** table have fields **bid, id, title, url, date**.

suppose [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is saved in **url field** and when I create link using following code

```
<a href="<?=$bookmark->url ?>" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Visit</a>
```

it open following link

http://localhost/myapp/bookmark/www.google.com

but I want to directly open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

simply add // before link eg

```
<a href="//<?=$bookmark->url ?>" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Visit</a>
```

also be sure that link will never have http or https
or add it to link on insert eg :
https://google.com
and then remove //